# Writing image files to folder in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Below is some code which is showing error

```
imgIndex = 1;
numPlotsR = size(ca, 1);
numPlotsC = size(ca, 2);
for r = 1 : numPlotsR 
for c = 1 : numPlotsC
rgbBlock=ca{r,c};
imagename=strcat(int2str(imgIndex), '.jpg');
name=strcat((int2str(our_images)),'\',imagename);
imwrite(rgbBlock,'name');
```

I am trying to write some image file to folder using imwrite. But the last 3 lines is showing error. I need to save all the images which I have created.

Comment: What value is on 'our_images' ? And what error is Matlab showing ?

Comment: try `imwrite( rgbBlock, name );` without the quotes on `'name'`.

Comment: please consider using `fullfile` command to create file names with paths.

Comment: Also, consider isolating the error in a self-contained-working example, so we can run it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that `our_images` is the name of the folder when you want your images, so instead of this:

```
name=strcat((int2str(our_images)),'\',imagename);
```

you need this:

```
name=strcat(our_images,'/',imagename);
```

Also look out for the backslash in there.

Also your `name` variable should not be quoted here:

```
imwrite(rgbBlock,'name');
```

So instead it should be:

```
imwrite(rgbBlock, name);
```

Comment: nope that does not work.All the inputs must be two dimensional is the error its showing

Comment: How are you assigning `our_images` ?

Comment: our_images = imread(full_name); our_image is the image that we read

Comment: In that case you should not concatenate it in `strcat(our_images,'\',imagename);` , instead you should use something like: `strcat(path_to_images,'/',imagename);`

Comment: (I think the answers to shai go in the other comments section)

Comment: ..it works @  DWilches!!!!!thanks i made these changes imagename=strcat(int2str(imgIndex), '.jpg');
        name=strcat('C:\Users\Newfolder\our_images','/',imagename);
        %save inside output folder
 imwrite(rgbBlock, name);